# Is it possible to check if the caps lock button is active while typing in form?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it was possible to know if the caps lock button is active while filling a web form ?

Sometimes, when you are asked to enter your password, softwares notice you that's active, and you be careful.

I would have liked to do the same in web forms.

Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you tell if caps lock is on using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The following jQuery snippet detects whether caps lock is enabled upon keypress:

```
$('#example').keypress(function(e) { 
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        alert('caps is on');
    }
});
```

Taken from StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/896515/1113435

Comment: This appears to be a pretty solid solution. jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/p25sq/

Comment: Note that this solution works only on keypress but when using keydown or keyup then String.fromCharCode() always returns the uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checar_caps_lock(ev) {
    var e 

    = ev || window.event;
        codigo_tecla = e.keyCode?e.keyCode:e.which;
        tecla_shift = e.shiftKey?e.shiftKey:((codigo_tecla == 16)?true:false);
        if(((codigo_tecla >= 65 && codigo_tecla <= 90) && !tecla_shift) || ((codigo_tecla >= 97 && codigo_tecla <= 122) && tecla_shift)) {
            document.getElementById('aviso_caps_lock').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('aviso_caps_lock').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input name="nome_do_campo" type="text" onkeypress="checar_caps_lock(event)" />
    <div id="aviso_caps_lock" style="visibility: hidden">CAPS LOCK ATIVADO</div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that this only works with keypress and not with keyup and keydown. Just to know, this:

```
$("#example").keypress(function(e) {
    console.log("keypress: " + e.which);
});
$("#example").keydown(function(e) {
    console.log("keydown: " + e.which);
});
$("#example").keyup(function(e) {
    console.log("keyup: " + e.which);
});
```

("a" pressed) returns this:

```
keydown: 65
keypress: 97
keyup: 65
```

Note: tried with chrome and firefox

Answer (score -1):

Accessing user setting like that would be against any decent security model, however you could check for whether the user has entered ALL_CAPS or aLL_CAPS and warn appropriately.

An elegant work-around can be found here: http://24ways.org/2007/capturing-caps-lock

> Sadly, there’s no way of actually detecting whether Caps Lock is on directly. However, there’s a simple work-around; if the user presses a key, and it’s a capital letter, and they don’t have the Shift key depressed, why then they must have Caps Lock on! Simple.

Comment: I definitly think parsing user input like that would be a bad idea !
my password could be FOOBAR and i don't want to be noticed !
It should not disable the input to the user, but just notice him, that's caps lock is active.

Comment: Yes, detect the shift key not the caps lock - simple and clever!