# How do I detect the CAPS LOCK state in a password field

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you tell if caps lock is on using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript)

In a web form, is there any way to tell if the caps lock is on ?

I suppose I could check do a check `onChange` to see if all the characters are upper case. But is there a more direct way to do this?

Specifically, I am looking to implement a "YOUR CAPS LOCK IS ON" message when they enter the password field, similar to how the windows login screen does .

Comment: I hope there isn't because that should rather be a job for the browser.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript

Comment: just check if the character is capitalized and shift is not clicked, then warn the user..

Comment: @ifaour that sounds like a great idea! Might be worth an answer.

Comment: @Pekka: There already is one, uhm... are many; e.g., check the dupe provided by McStretch.

Comment: @Marcel yeah, I just saw. Voted as a dupe.

Comment: @Marcel - Funny, I didn't find that one when I searched. Thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a decent example of how to do this here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Detect_Caps_Lock.aspx

You could take that code and wrap it into a different kind of event, either, i.e. onfocus or on document load.

You can google for an index of key codes (I'd post a link, but I don't have high enough karma to post more than one link, sorry).

For simplicity the codes you'd be looking for is 20 (Caps  lock).

---

Instructions copied here from site (license: [CPOL](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx))

### Building the script

```
<script language="Javascript">
function capLock(e){
 kc = e.keyCode?e.keyCode:e.which;
 sk = e.shiftKey?e.shiftKey:((kc == 16)?true:false);
 if(((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk)||((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk))
  document.getElementById('divMayus').style.visibility = 'visible';
 else
  document.getElementById('divMayus').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Now we have our script ready to go. We now need to associate this script with our form.

### Using the script

Let's add two items: a textbox and a DIV. Now we just need to call the onKeyPress event.

```
<input type="password" name="txtPassword" onkeypress="capLock(event)" />
<div id="divMayus" style="visibility:hidden">Caps Lock is on.</div>
```

Comment: This does not detect whether Caps Lock is on. It detects whether Caps Lock was turned on while on the page, but not if it was already on.

Comment: In 2017+, use [`event.getModifierState('CapsLock');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState)
 - ([caniuse?](http://caniuse.com/#search=getModifierState))