# Javascript - check if CAPS LOCK is ON on load of HTML page. Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, onload, keyboard-events, capslock

I want to alert to user if CAPS LOCK is ON when HTML page get load.

I have tried search in google and got multiple views from people some are saying possible some are saying not possible.

I have code which will alert to user only when they type something through keyboard.

```
document.onkeypress = function ( e ) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.keyCode || e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && !e.shiftKey ) { // incomplete: shift + caps MAY =  lowercase
        alert('caps is on')
    }
}
```

Working.

**Is it possible to alert on load of HTML page?**

**PS:**

[Check Scroll Lock, Num Lock & Caps Lock in JavaScript on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060073/check-scroll-lock-num-lock-caps-lock-in-javascript-on-page-load)

http://dougalmatthews.com/2008/Jul/02/javascript-detecting-caps-lock/

Comment: Why did you  link to a duplicate in your question?

Comment: You have your answer in the question you linked to...

Comment: ...and it looks like there are a bunch of other potential duplicates in the **Related** list to the right.

Comment: @cookiemonster in first link is saying...not possible... so i am confused....trying to find out possible or not...

Comment: @BillyMathews so are you saying its not possible to check CAPS LOCK onload of html page...

Comment: If you don't believe the answer given there, why would you believe an answer given here?

Comment: http://dougalmatthews.com/2008/Jul/02/javascript-detecting-caps-lock/

Comment: @cookiemonster so its not about believe... as you can see that question is **answered Jan 30 '12 at 6:19**... 2 years back... may be someone has found out a way to check this thing... right?

Comment: Check if [this plugin](https://github.com/nosilleg/capslockstate-jquery-plugin) helps. Otherwise your solution is the way to go. Like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript).

Comment: Why do you need it on page load in the first place? What are you ultimately trying to do that can't wait for the user to offer a key event?

Comment: good question.. :) so basically i am automating a application where i am take input from excel file and user will not be type anything on that webpage... so i want to keep a check in starting itself...

Comment: if they aren't typing, what's it matter anyway?

Comment: If capslock is not then upper case invoice number converts into lower case once in while...