# jquery not able to detect the caps lock on and off and keypress are capital or small

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 challenges,

1. On page load, I would like to show a warning saying that "caps is on".
2. Still the user press the shift + key or Caps on + key - I would like to through error.

I search in google and find a solution, but it doesn't work. any one help me to sort this issue please? please refresh the page using caps lock on/off to get the current status. nothing works.

Here is the function I got from google search:

```
function capLock(e){
 kc = e.keyCode?e.keyCode:e.which;
 sk = e.shiftKey?e.shiftKey:((kc == 16)?true:false);
 if(((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk)||((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk))
  console.log('caps lock on')
 else
  console.log('caps lock off');
}

$('#password').on('keypress', function(e){
    capLock(e.which)
})
```

[online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73hvf/)

Comment: Can't be detected, only heuristically guessed at.

Comment: there is no way to find the caps is on or off while load the page?. Actually the answers what on the question all was tried. problem is there is no proper deduction for on page load again mixing cpas+shit and shif+char and caps+shift+char - is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XRbhu/2/)**
      Don't pass e.which .you have to pass event

```
 function capLock(e) {
        kc = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        sk = e.shiftKey ? e.shiftKey : ((kc == 16) ? true : false);
        if (((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk) || ((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk)) console.log('caps lock on')
        else console.log('caps lock off');
    }

    $('#password').on('keypress', function (e) {
        capLock(e)
    });
```

Comment: How to find on document load, the caps lock is on or off?

Comment: @3gwebtrain Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371732/detect-caps-lock-status-on-page-load-or-similar

Comment: Your demo is not working properly. please press the key using "shift" key pressed on caps on/off status.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are passing `e.which` instead of `e` while calling `capLock` function.

Try this : Pass only event `e` while calling `capLock` function.

```
$('#password').on('keypress', function(e){
    capLock(e);
})
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73hvf/1/)

Comment: While using shift key pressed not working your demo. please check

Comment: Do want to check cap on/off or want to check if it is capital letter or not?

Comment: YES. EXACTLY. some times while the page load itself the caps may switched on by user... that is the issue.

Comment: so as per your script, it will only check if cap is on or off and it is working fine.

Comment: I added my answer, can you test that?

Comment: you can also use jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/73hvf/1/ to test or share your code. Just add your code in respective areas like html, javascript, css and click on Update button on the top. On update, url get changed everytime and hence you can share this url to others to share your code or problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used a new approach to find the letters on key press: here is my solution:

```
    $('#password').keypress(function(e) { 
    var Caps = null;
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        Caps = true;
    } else {
        Caps = false;
    }

    if(s.toUpperCase() === s){
        Caps = true;
    }else{
        Caps = false;
    }

    if(Caps){
        console.log('no use of the caps letter');
    }
});
```

any comment or correction or update.. expected. thanks