# How can I check if capslock is on without waiting for the user to type character using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, capslock

Gmail shows an icon in Chrome when the user has capslock on and focuses on the password field, how are they able to do that?

There are many related question to this, but no one seem to know how to do it without user input, like:

- [How do you tell if caps lock is on using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript)

Comment: Nowadays you can do this. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62714450/851957) on another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, this is a native function of the Chrome browser when focusing on password field, clever!

Comment: I'd like to do this in browsers other than Chrome, it would still be nice to know if it is possible.

Comment: @MartinBrown It's not possible without user input.