# Capslock detection won't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am trying to detect capslock in Javascript, however the code below always returns false. Firefox and IE web console says that kc and sk are undefined. `Event "e"` seems to contain a which element, however `e.which` is undefined.

Am I doing something incorrect? I am using devexpress (could this be an issue?)

**Javascript**

```
 <script>
    function isCapslock(e) {

      kc = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      sk = e.shiftKey ? e.shiftKey : ((kc == 16) ? true : false);
      if (((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk) || ((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk))
          return true;
      else
          return false; 
      }
```

function showCapsWarning(e) {

```
        if (isCapslock(e)) {
            document.getElementById("capsWarningDiv").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("capsWarningDiv").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

    }
</script>
```

**aspx file**

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="tbPassword" Password="True"                                              ToolTip="Please enter your password."
        Width="300px"  
        ClientSideEvents-KeyPress="function(s,e) {showCapsWarning(e); }"
                                                    >
```

This is where I got the capslock javascript code from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17180/Detect-Caps-Lock-with-Javascript

Comment: Where is `showCapsWarning`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it! I edited the question.

Comment: Try inverting the order of parameters of the keypress handler: `function(e, s) {showCapsWarning(e); }`

Comment: the event gets sent over to the function correctly. Thanks for your help but I figured out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.which was undefined within the web developer console. I noticed that the event object was using the following path in order to get to the which element: `event.htmlEvent.which`. Once I used `e.htmlEvent` it began to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think a little bit late, but check this codepen: https://codepen.io/sarkiroka/full/qBbpKYY

The main idea is since 2017 every browser supports getModifierState on keyboard and mouse envents. Check this boolean to show or hide the red warning area.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('password');
input.addEventListener('keyup', checkCapsLock);
input.addEventListener('mousedown', checkCapsLock);
let previousStateOfCapsLock=false;
function handleWarning(show){
  document.getElementById('capsLockWarning').style.display=show?'block':'none';
}
function checkCapsLock(event) {
    let isCaps = event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
  if (previousStateOfCapsLock && event.key=='CapsLock') { // now turn it off
    isCaps = false;
  }
  previousStateOfCapsLock = isCaps;
  handleWarning(isCaps);
}
```

```css
.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password"></input>
<p class="error" id="capsLockWarning">
  The Caps Lock is ON!
</p>
```