# How can use "getModifierState" on focus event with JS?

Tags: javascript, focus, addeventlistener, modifier

I'm trying to get caps lock status on focus event of input this is my code

```
$('#Input')[0].addEventListener('focus', function (key) {
                         if (key.originalEvent.getModifierState("CapsLock"))
                            //do something...
                        else {
                            //do something..
                        }
                });
```

But i'm getting this error "Cannot read property 'getModifierState' of undefined", and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Some advice or link for to read thanks in advance.

Comment: Just in case we can come up with another approach for you, what are you trying to do with the information? For instance, are you trying to warn the user that they have Caps Lock on when they focus a password field? If so, you could do it in response to `keydown` events. Not quite as good, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of event object. `getModifierState` is only defined for `KeyboardEvent` (such as a `keydown`) and `MouseEvent` (such as a `click`); `focus` is neither.

<s>You might look at using `click` and remembering whether you already had focus (e.g., so you don't repeat the action if the click is in an already-focussed element).</s> Ugh, no, that's a terrible suggestion. There are lots of ways your element might get focus other than clicks.

Comment: Thanks for the info