# Detect if capslock is down

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need is to detect, whether the caps lock key at the very moment is down. So I don't need the state (on/off), I want to check if the user keeps the caps lock pressed down. Is it possible with javascript? I want to create something like an Enso Launcher inside the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you tell if caps lock is on using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP emphasised that he doesn't ask for the state of CapsLock (on/off), but the act of holding the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check if the user keeps the caps lock pressed down.

On most browsers, you'll get `keydown` and `keyup` events for CapsLock, [try it here](http://jsbin.com/ecikif) (just focus the page and press a key). ([This article](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) has lots of useful info about keyboard events.)

`keydown` doesn't seem to repeat for CapsLock, the way it does for others, but you can watch for `keydown` and assume it's down until you see `keyup`.