# Is it possible to trigger a keyboard button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events, case-sensitive, capslock

Is it possible to trigger a keyboard button with JavaScript, and to get a input-case depending on the Caps Lock button?

So, if my Caps Lock is on, "IT SHOULD BE UPPERCASED" or "it should be lowercased if it's off".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript#answer-348802

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you tell if caps lock is on using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger an key event:

```
var ev = jQuery.Event("keypress");
ev.ctrlKey = false;
ev.which = 37;
$("container").trigger(ev);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This site might help you: 
http://dougalmatthews.com/articles/2008/jul/2/javascript-detecting-caps-lock/
But notice you can call this function only on a user executed key-press. So your user has to have pressed at least one key to detect whether CapsLock is on.

Comment: yes, I notice that... using your example, I could automize it more ;) thank you

Answer (score 1):

javascript event object gives you different key code depending on either you capslock is pressed or not.

```
$('#yourTxtBox').keypress(function(e){

//eg:for small case letter 'a' it give you '65' and for capital 'A' it gives you '97'

    console.log(e.which);

});
```

so you can easily identify that your capslock is pressed or not.