# How to press a key using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to know how to get a certain key on the keyboard to be pressed via code on nodejs.

For instance, I want the f3 button to pressed once the following page is rendered:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   // press key
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs how to read keystrokes from stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006821/nodejs-how-to-read-keystrokes-from-stdin)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17473563/7707749, it might be what you search for.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  Certainly not with the server-side code that you're demonstrating.  And while I've not done the research, I can't imagine that browser JS's sandbox would allow direct hardware simulation like that either.  Why do you need F3 hit? What do you expect to happen? Are you assuming all computer F3 buttons do the same thing?

Comment: @codekid and King Reload> read the question. He is not trying to read keyboard input, he's trying to *cause* the F3 to be hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`robotjs`](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs), which can be used to generate keyboard events.

For instance, to "send" an F3 key press:

```
const robot = require('robotjs');
...
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  robot.keyTap('f3');
  res.end();
});
```

Although it depends on which OS you're using if this is going to work as expected.

Comment: THis is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from server side.
You can include a javascript script in your page which can trigger the event.
If you are using jQuery.

```
var ev = jQuery.Event("keypress");
ev.ctrlKey = false;
ev.which = 37;
$("container").trigger(ev);
```

[Is it possible to trigger a keyboard button with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009932/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-keyboard-button-with-javascript)

Comment: Thank you I have added $('#close-btn').click(function(){
    var ev = jQuery.Event("keypress");
ev.ctrlKey = false;
ev.which = 37;
$("container").trigger(ev);
}); for the following button  <button id="close-btn" class="btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Close application</button>

Comment: but it doesnt seem to work when button click (f3 close the application)

Comment: If your intention is for any hardware simulation, it is not possible.
This will only trigger any event handler

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use applescript in nodejs, and node-key-sender on other platform.

```
const os = require('os')
const childProcess = require('child_process')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const ks = require('node-key-sender')  

function hitHotkey (key, modifier) {
    if (os.type() === 'Darwin') {
      if (modifier) {
        return exec(`Script="tell app \\"System Events\\" to keystroke ${key} using ${modifier} down"
        osascript -e "$Script"`)
      } else {
        return exec(`Script="tell app \\"System Events\\" to keystroke ${key}"
        osascript -e "$Script"`)
      }
    } else {
      if (modifier) {
        return ks.sendCombination([modifier, key])
      } else {
        return ks.sendKey(key)
      }
    }
  }
```