# Javascript String.fromCharCode Case Sensitivity?

Tags: javascript, string, fromcharcode

I am simply listening for a keyup event of an input element and gather the results into a string like so

```
word=word+String.fromCharCode(key.keyCode);
```

The problem is that the word is in capital letters while I want it to be case-sensitive.
For example if I type abcef my accumulated word becomes 'ABCEF' .

Note - I need a pure javascript solution (no libraries..)
Any thoughts?

Comment: 65 is the code for upper-case "A", not lower-case.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(key.keyCode).toLowerCase()` ??

Comment: So what is the keycode for lower-case a ? Can't find an answer in google...

Comment: The 'keyup' event will return 65 for both, but a 'keypress' event should return 97 for lowercase!

Comment: @adeneo yep you nailed it !! that was the problem , I used keyup which behaves differently than expected . U can write that as an answer so I can accept it ...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Events like `keyup` and `keydown` will return 65 for both `a` and `A` *(and also `true` for `event.shiftKey` if that key is held down)*.

The `keypress` event returns different keycodes for upper and lower case letters, so to get this working case sensitive you should use the `keypress` event, and `fromCharCode()` will return the correct letter, case sensitive.

Comment: You can always check if event.shiftKey is true or false and apply a .toLowerCase()

Comment: I think you need to check, because some kepress events cannot be canceled like keydowns

Answer (score 3):

You can always call `.toLowerCase()`

```
word = word + String.fromCharCode(key.keyCode).toLowerCase();
```

Might make more sense to call `.toLowerCase()` just once, at the point you decide you're finished accumulating characters.

Comment: I would recommend against this if a native solution is available.