# Add popover to input field on detection of Caps Lock using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have an ASP.NET C# Web Application login form. I want my form to detect when the user's caps lock is on, when the password input field is clicked on. Here's the caps lock detection code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
```

and in my page load

```
bool CapsLock =  (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
if (CapsLock = true)
{

}
```

when `CapsLock = true`, I want an alert panel to become visible to warn the users that their Capslock is on. Then, when the user turns off caps lock I want the alert panel's visibility to be set to false. How can this be done?

OR

if I use javascript instead:

```
/* check for CAPS LOCK on all password fields */
$("input[type='password']").keypress(function(e) {
    var kc = e.which; // get keycode

    var isUpperCase = ((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) || (kc >= 33 && kc <= 34) || (kc >= 36 && kc <= 39) || (kc >= 40 && kc <= 42) || kc == 47 || (kc >= 58 && kc <= 59) || kc == 61 || kc == 63 || kc == 167 || kc == 196 || kc == 214 || kc == 220) ? true : false; // uppercase A-Z or 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü', '!', '"', '§', '$', '%', '&', '/', '(', ')', '=', ':', ';'
    var isLowerCase = ((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) || (kc >= 48 && kc <= 57) || kc == 35 || (kc >= 43 && kc <= 44) || kc == 46 || kc == 228 || kc == 223 || kc == 246 || kc == 252) ? true : false; // lowercase a-Z or 0-9 or 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', '.', ','

    // event.shiftKey does not seem to be normalized by jQuery(?) for IE8-
    var isShift = (e.shiftKey) ? e.shiftKey : ((kc == 16) ? true : false); // shift is pressed

    // uppercase w/out shift or lowercase with shift == caps lock
    if ((isUpperCase && !isShift) || (isLowerCase && isShift)) {
        $(this).next('.form-control-feedback').show().parent().addClass('has-warning has-feedback').next(".capsWarn").show();
    } else {
        $(this).next('.form-control-feedback').hide().parent().removeClass('has-warning has-feedback').next(".capsWarn").hide();
    }
}).after('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" style="display:none;"></span>').parent().after("<span class='capsWarn text-danger' style='display:none;'>Is your CAPSLOCK on?</span>");
```

how can I refer my asp:textbox field in this line: `$("input[type='password']").keypress(function(e)`?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript