# keyDown event is not fired for Capslock in Mac

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keyboard-events, capslock

CHROME (52):

When turning caps lock ON - only keydown is fired (no event in keyUp or keyPress)

When turning caps lock OFF - only keyup is fired (no event in keyDown or keyPress)

FIREFOX (46):

Only keyDown event is fired for both caps lock ON & OFF (no keyUp or keyPress)

I've read about the keyCodes and events here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html and in MDN here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode, aaaand here http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

But none of the above links talks about this weird behaviour.
Is this expected? If so, any easier way to handle it?

Comment: Out of interest, what are you using caps lock for? As a user, I almost think of caps lock as "not a key", and am slightly surprised it fires any events at all!

Comment: lol, I'm designing a small quick-hands-game inspired from dota. Based on comfort, people keep caps lock as a key since it's very close to the W-A-S-D.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if it was a game. Cheers. Good luck!

Comment: @BharathRaja My answer may help you :P !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is expected.

Chrome treats the **CAPS ON** as `keydown` because it treats the on/off as press and hold, like we hold **shift** key, which turns on caps on behaviour and turns off when we release it. This **Caps Lock** button also. When you turn on **Caps Lock**, chrome handles the **'turn on'** as a `keypress` and when you **'turn off'** it handles it as a `keyup`. But, firefox handles everything as `keydown` which doesn't make sense to me when compared to how chrome handles the same.

**Solution**

You should use [getModifierState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState) to get the state of the `Caps Lock`. This is supported in chrome and firefox.

Hope it helps!

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.which === 20)
      console.log(e.originalEvent.getModifierState('CapsLock'))
  });
  $(window).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 20)
      console.log(e.originalEvent.getModifierState('CapsLock'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Focus here and press 'Caps Lock'
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like the closest solution we could get. Though for a quick-key-press game with a timer, handling the `keyup` event instead of the `keydown` event makes a huge difference :(

Answer (score -1):

I had been looking for an answer to a very similar issue. Pranesh's answer pointed me in a direction.

In my case, I wanted to warn users that their capslock is on when they go to log in. Ultimately I settled on the following solution.

Angular Component:

```
export class AuthenticateComponent {
  public capslockOn: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.capslockOn = false;
  }

  public keyup(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.key === 'CapsLock') {
      // Checks / sets when the Caps Lock key is specifically pressed.
      this.capslockOn = (!this.capslockOn && event.getModifierState('CapsLock'));
    } else {
      // Checks all other conditions like the Caps Lock was on before the user
      // loaded the form and began typing in it.
      this.capslockOn = event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
    }
  }
}
```

Then I just call the `keyup` function from my form:

```
<form ... (keyup)="keyup($event)">
```

Any keypress in the form - username or password - will check / set the boolean `capslockOn` and I can *ngIf that to show an icon or message or both.

Thanks for the explanation Pranesh. It helped quite a bit.