# Override / reuse Caps lock message in asp net site when textmode is password

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I created a new Webforms project (Visual Studio 2015) and in the login page when CAPS LOCK is on I get the message in the picture, I want to reuse this way of showing messages over textboxes, but can't find where is defined, I'm guessing is in the jquery file, but can't find it because I don't know exactly what I'm looking for... I'm sorry if this has been asked before and for my english.

[Caps lock message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEIZK.png)

Comment: Lots of things to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript - getModifierState seems to be best solution but check browser compatability. PS. this is somethign you need to do in JavaScript so nothing to do with ASP.NET or Web Forms.

Comment: I understand that it is a javascript solution (maybe i wasn't clear enough in my question),but when you create a solution in asp .net you get that caps lock message out of the box, the code for that has to be somewhere right?

Comment: Sorry, just re read your question and I got it way wrong