# Change input to Upper Case with CapsLock on

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I would just like to know is it possible to change the input automatically to `capitalized` on a certain `input` field where the user entered a value with Caps Lock on.

```
 <input placeholder="Brand Name" style="text-transform: capitalized" type="text" />
```

**Caps On** = TEST NAME

Expected: Test Name

```
 <input placeholder="Brand Name" style="text-transform: capitalized" type="text" />
```

**Caps Off** = test name

Default: Test Name

I know some Names looks like `Reader Van der Bank` where not all the name parts are capitalized, but still would like to know if its possible. Thanks

Alternative : Think i might be using a php function to transform everything to lowercase and then capitalized.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript

Comment: @epascarello might be a case where i tell the user caps is on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a javascript function to do that, if there is no CSS solution for it.

```js
var id = document.getElementById("test");

function change() {
  var arr = id.value.split(" ").map(function(x) {
    return x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase()
  });
  id.value = arr.join(" ");
}
id.addEventListener("change", change);
id.addEventListener("keyup", change);
```

```html
<input placeholder="Brand Name" id="test" type="text" />
```

For multiple elements with class `test`

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

function change() {
  var arr = this.value.split(" ").map(function(x) {
    return x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase()
  });
  this.value = arr.join(" ");
}


for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("change", change);
  elements[i].addEventListener("keyup", change);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Brand Name" class="test" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Brand Name" class="test" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Brand Name" class="test" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Brand Name" class="test" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Brand Name" class="test" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Brand Name" class="test" type="text" />
```

Comment: why does this not work for `var id = document.getElementsByClassName("test");`  getting value by class?

Comment: i would like to implement this on a class where its based on more than one input field and not add an id to each input field, to repetitive.

Comment: @Ylama Did you set class to `test`?

Comment: yess i did.. and added it to more than one input field.

Comment: ` <input class="up" placeholder="Brand Name">` AND ` <input class="up" placeholder="Product Name">`

Answer (score 1):

```
style="text-transform: capitalize"
```

(Question was edited. New Answer.)

Give your input an id, for this example let's say it's called "theInputId".
Then add an onkeypress event to it also and call the function script I've listed below.

```
<input placeholder="Brand Name" style="text-transform: capitalized" 
 type="text" id="theInputId" onkeypress="capsLock(event)">


<script>
//Script to check if Caps Lock is on.
function capLock(e){
kc = e.keyCode?e.keyCode:e.which;
sk = e.shiftKey?e.shiftKey:((kc == 16)?true:false);
if(((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk)||((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk)){
document.getElementById('theInputId').style.textTransform = 'lowercase'
document.getElementById('theInputId').style.textTransform = 'capitalize'
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to  enter all the text capitalized in the input? then u can use text-`transform:uppercase` in css and if u want to change it while typing you can use `toUpperCase()` on `keyup` of that input.

Comment: sorry capitalized dont work, i edited my question.. was a typo for the inline styling