# How to detect Caps Lock is ON on web browser on Android Devices using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, android-browser, capslock

We can **very well detect CapsLock is ON/not on iPhone web browser** using [KeyboardEvent.getModifierState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState), with sample code,

```
function checkCapsLock(e) {
  if (e.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
    alert("Caps ON");
  }
}
```

But **it doesn't work on a browser on Android Devices**. I've tried many other solutions using charCode, keyCode, shiftKey, which, etc. methods on the event with listeners like keyup, keydown, keypress, etc. But no luck.

I've gone through the answers mentioned on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript), and other links too. But still no luck.

Is there any workaround for this?

I'm asking about the issue on the Android web browser!

With [Key Event Viewer](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html), we can observe that CapsLock can be detected on Web or mobile web browser on iPhone, but not on a web browser on Android devices.

Comment: It should work the same way. What browser/version do you use?

Comment: @ThomasSablik: I've checked on Android Chrome browser v89.0.4389.0.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState says it should work since Chrome 48.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Exactly, even I checked on [can I use](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-getmodifierstate), but still, it's not behaving as expected!

Comment: I checked it on https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html It looks like JavaScript can't distinguish c, Shift-c, and Caps-Lock-c. It registered 3 equal events for me.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: On the link, if you check on the Android browser, if we press Shift, it doesn't show anything! As we'll be using Shift to make CapsLock ON.
However, the same thing if we do on iPhone, works very well!

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle As I said on the gist you commented on, each software keyboard treats listeners differently. Depending on the software keyboard being used, you may notice that events aren't fired properly. Which soft-keyboard are you using?

Comment: @JasonN.Gaylord: This issue is there on Android devices, Remi Note (7,8), Google Pixel, OnePlus, etc!

Comment: Our experience is frustratingly the same with Android phones as per @JasonN.Gaylord comment due to the software keyboard being used, not the browser or the Android OS. Hence, you will find industry wide that password fields contain a 'SHOW' button to ensure your password is not all CAPS, as the webform cannot detect 'CAPS LOCK ON' from the software keyboard. The android OS and web browsers are fine. You can verify this by connecting a physical keyboard to your android device, use it with an android browser and 'CAPS LOCK ON' will be detected. We tested a Bluetooth and a USB (via OTG) keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

While this code works on some Android devices, it won't work on all, because the `e.ShiftKey` turns out to be false in Android. On android, it actually depends on your keyboard.

This is the best, I was able to come up with.

```js
document.addEventListener ('keyup', function (event){ 
        
    let status = checkCapsLock(event);
    
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += ('<span class="'+ status +'">Status: ' + status + '</span>');

});  
 

function checkCapsLock(e) {
  e = e ? e : window.event;
  
  if (e.getModifierState('CapsLock'))
    return true;
    
  let isShiftOn = e.shiftKey;
  
  let s = e.key;
  
  if(s.length != 1){
  let keyCode = e.keyCode; //e.KeyCode is always 229 on Android;
      if(keyCode == 229) 
        s = (e.target.value).split('').pop();
  }
     
  if ( (s.length != 0 ) && (s.toUpperCase() === s) && !isShiftOn )
        return true;
  return false;
}
```

```css
span{
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

span.true{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
Input: <input id="targetInput">
<p id="status"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this also triggers green output when we just press Shift + any other char!