# How do you check if CapsLock is initially on, without event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, capslock

I have been looking through the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript), and it is pretty much just a ton of answers showing different ways to check if CapsLock is on, with some event listener.

In those many solutions, I found one that I think is the best of them all, but there is one problem with all of them. They all depend on some sort of input (`onkeyup` or `click` listeners are used), I would like to (if possible) do a check the instant the page is loaded to check if CapsLock is currently on, and then use the solution I chose, to check if the CapsLock state changes during input.

Is this possible?
Is there some way that we can just use the `event.getModifierState` without having an `event`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use an event? That's what they're for.

Comment: @Christopher - are you sure?

Comment: @ggorlen that relies on keypresses occuring

Comment: @Christopher - *it should* - why should it? there's no reason why an artificially created keypress event should detect the state of the hardware

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use an event, it's that I want to do it when the page loads. So far the only solutions require a certain type of `eventListener` and uses the event.

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing... a static version of the KeyboardEvent.getModifierState function, so you can display the state of the Caps Lock key on page load.

Comment: I have not found anything. And have not heard anything more about this... As of right now, I do not think it is possible.