# How to enable/disable the caps lock or num lock key using nodejs or angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, electron

I want to handle the CapsLock and NumLock key using angular or node js. So is there any way to do that?

I have tried the `dispatchEvent` but it does not working.

Comment: Even if you could (which I doubt), it's hard to imagine a use case for this that wouldn't be surprising and irritating to users. Maybe you have one, but it's hard to imagine...

Comment: Angular runs in a browser, and browsers certainly don't have the ability to do this for security reasons. Make sure you're clear on where your code is running - it sounds like you want a web app to take over control of the user's keyboard, which is forbidden, but if you're building an app in node to distribute some other way, it may be possible.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of what you need to do. You've tagged [tag:electron] -- is this in an Electron app? It **may** be possible in the server part of that. Almost certainly not in the browser part where the tags [tag:angular] and [tag:jquery] would apply.

Comment: Yes, it's an electron app. I want to check that does my CapsLock is on or not. if not then I want to on it when my app loads or refreshes.

Comment: Just FWIW, as a user, if an app turned CapsLock on every time I went into it, I'd immediately uninstall the app. Instead, can't you treat input as case-insensitive, showing it in all caps (if that's really appropriate -- note it's harder to read all caps than properly capitalized text).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , I do not have any input to take and show in capslock, I have to enable the capslock for the other things.

Comment: There's no need for mystery: ***What*** "other things"?

Comment: If you want make all letter uppercase in an input, you can use, css uppercase, or js 'string'.toUpperCase(). But if you really need to control the keyboard device, i think the only way is to use electron bridge, to be abble to make system calls, or c++ implementations

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There is a device I am connecting, which bulb a light so as I checked when I have a capslock on it bubbled the light. And when the capslock is off it does not show any light. so I want to keep the capslock on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34277417/3910390

Comment: @Penguin - OP wants to **set** the state, not read it.